# How can one confirm creation of magnetic graphene?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, graphene

Recently my high school physics teacher contacted me looking for an expert to ask about this situation. I am paraphrasing his correspondence below:

> I just had a a student accidentally create magnetic graphene.  This has been done before,  but we did it very simply by exfoiliating with a magntic stirrer in the presence of a surfactant for over a week. **I would like to confirm our discovery,  but lack the knowledge and ability to thoroughly test.**
>
> It appears that this phenomenon is paramagnetic in nature.  The graphene only attracts to a strong magnet when in the presence a constantly changing magnetic field.  When the external spinning magnet slows the effect diminishes to zero.

<s>He also provided a youtube video of the experiment.</s> (removed since it is too double edged.)

So, I am turning to the experts here to get advice on the boldface text in the correspondence. What can/should be done to confirm creation of magnetic graphene?

Please note - this question is not about the method used to create, or not create, what may or may not be magnetic graphene. The question is "If I gave you a sample X and asked you to confirm it was magnetic graphene, what experiment might you do?"

---

UPDATE: (Sorry for the delay) After further tests, my teacher concluded that iron contamination was causing what he observed. Sorry for the anti-climax, but the question is basically not an issue anymore. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: This site has a rule about mainstream physics. Mainstream physics, by the usual definitions of scientific work, has been published and peer reviewed.  Your submission here doesn't even come close to what I would call a proper description of an experiment, let alone something that can be peer reviewed. On the other hand, the sceptic in me thinks that what you are really trying to do is to get the views up on your Youtube video so you can make money with it.

Comment: @CuriousOne Well, I can see why possibly you might suspect that at first glance, but from my good standing at math.SE I hope you can guess that I am not interested in embarrassing myself.  From my teacher's related vids, you can tell he is not concerned with gaining views. That said, your concern is unfounded. The situation really is as I'm describing it. Whatever deficiency exists, please describe it and I will try to rectify it. Thank you

Comment: I will give you the benefit of the doubt, but there is really no point in me commenting on what sounds like a chemistry experiment on Youtube. Movies are the lowest quality of documentation for an experiment and as a general principle I usually ignore them. It takes a detailed writeup of materials and procedures plus observations and, in case of an unexpected result, the willingness of another scientist to replicate the experiment to make any progress. If your teacher can get this published in a science journal AND somebody replicates it, then I will care. Best of luck!

Comment: I will take it as an action item to get details on the experiment in writing so that I can just remove the vid. Seems like it is only a distraction.

Comment: Videos can be easily faked. The only thing no person can fake is the experiment I repeat in my lab all by myself. It seems necessary that we start teaching the practice of good science in high school, again, it's obvious that the internet culture of "monkey sees, monkey believes" has taken a bite out of rational thinking.

Comment: @CuriousOne I already understand: this is not something we have to contend with much at math.SE since suspicious poster rarely resort to YouTube videos for proofs. Usually it is just "read my 2 page paper in which I prove Fermat's last theorem." (2 is sometimes replaced with 200)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34786/discussion-between-curiousone-and-rschwieb).

Comment: Yes I think more information would be necessary to create an actual DOE.  What is the size of the graphene flake?  Have you infact confirmed it is graphene? What substrate is being used?  Have you performed a control on the substrate?  Think there are a lot of questions to answer before you can start testing this claim

Comment: Hopefully I will be able to start answering these questions with forthcoming details.

Comment: Re your update: one of my favorite professors likes to say "Nothing resembles a new effect quite so much as a mistake"